# ls filter on channelsftp

Tags: java, sftp, ls

Are there any way to filter the files to list using this api? for example:

```
    ChannelSftp sftpChannel;
    sftpChannel.ls(path);
```

This lists all, but I would like to filter the files that begin for AAA for example

Comment: Which library are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/), you should be able to use glob characters (`*` and `?`) in the last part of `path`. At least [this unofficial JavaDoc](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#ls%28java.lang.String%29) mentions this:

> The pattern can contain glob pattern wildcards (`*` or `?`) in the last component (i.e. after the last `/`).

So try

```
sftpChannel.ls(path + '/AAA*');
```

Comment: Is this functionality something that would be safe to assume is supported on all servers?  Is it a function of the connected server or is it doing something on the client side? I'm wondering what the chances are if I implement something to pass in a wildcard search if it could bomb out if it that wasn't supported on the server side.